# Vue/Laravel PayPal integration without smart buttons

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, paypal, vuejs2

I am really bothered by the fact that PayPal is forcing you to use their design on smart buttons so I wanted to integrate it in another way.

I have a Vue/Laravel app, and on Vue side, this is what it looks like:

```
<div class="column">
    <button class="button is-link is-fullwidth" @click="purchaseWithPayPal">
        <span class="icon">
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="paypalIcon"/>
        </span>
        <span>{{ $t('modal.paypal') }}</span>
    </button>
</div>


 ...

purchaseWithPayPal() {
    axios.post('api/paypal/make-payment', {
        amount: 5
    })
},
```

On Laravel side I was following [this post](https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-695063599449) to do the integration.

I did everything the same, but the issue is that upon successful creation of everything I am being redirected:

```
return redirect()->to($redirect_url);
```

and it is causing issues because of CORS related errors. I suppose this is due to the fact I am making an AJAX request which is then redirecting, but I don't see a way to make this a simple on-click event. How can I integrate it so that I use my design and circumvent the CORS issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've looked around https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart or the manual styling documentation, but there are quite a few design options for almost any site.

I would say the chief benefit is precisely *not* having to redirect, and instead having that modern 'in-context' experience, with your site kept loaded in the background.

But if you would truly prefer to redirect away from your site, the way I would do it is to return the URL in the ajax call, and then set `window.top.location.href` with the receiving client-side JS.

---

The exact problem you are having is that you are redirecting ***the ajax fetch itself***, so it is trying to ***fetch the PayPal site*** via XHR. You aren't actually redirecting the client-side window, in your current attempt.

Comment: The issue with manual styling is that predefined options to style exist. I am using Bulma as my CSS framework, and buttons don't look the same if I integrate PayPal button. I would like what you'd call in-context experience, but I don't know how can I do it with a custom design. Notice that besides PP I have Stripe and 3rd provider payment options, and it looks crappy if I have 3 different designs in a single modal

Comment: You can show just the PayPal button and have it be one of at least 10 different shape*color combinations, I'm surprised there isn't something that's a close enough fit. Having it stand out with the traditional PayPal yellow or blue background isn't a bad thing, customers recognize that

Comment: Color is not the issue, shape is. You can see that styling is not the same as other buttons. More even, having a Bulma button next to PP smart button, you can see that they are different. Similar yes, but same no. This is not UI I want as my OCD is screaming inside :)

Comment: Gotcha, well I always advise people that the distinctive PayPal button is worth having because there is a certain (sizable) chunk of customers that know it and trust it.  They may not be familiar with your site/business (yet), but they know PayPal, and so they're that much more likely to feel confident/safe enough in committing to that initial purchase. Basically it's worth it for sales.

Comment: I ended up as you said, returning the URL, then on successful callback calling `window.open(response.data.redirect, '_parent');`. Thanks